# Saving the state of HTML5 canvas after drag and drop.etc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop, kineticjs

I have created like a design studio and it has different functionalities like drag and drop,resize,text ,fonts, etc.
Example:User selects an image and then add some graphics over it and then add text over it,,.
is thr any way I can save the session and if the user resumes it later..
He gets the stuff the way he left it.
I don't need a jpeg image of the canvas..
I need to save the state so that user can manipulate it later..
Is it possible?
I have used kinetic js for this so if someone has any idea thn please help/

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at fabric.js, which allows to serialize entire state of the canvas (in its own object-based format), then restore it.

Comment: Actually M trying to understand it now..But for that I'll have to redo my whole app using Fabric.js ..and there are not enough examples of Fabric.js..and I can't find any example that will help me understand the functionality I require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yep, KineticJS will be releasing serialization and de-serialization this weekend :)

var json = stage.toJSON();

and

stage.load(json);

Cheers!

Comment: following up with this thread - KineticJS supports serialization as of  v3.9.2.  Cheers!